# Plotting explicit and implicit functions

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot these 3 functions:

```
z=y-1;
(x^2)+(y^2)=2x;
(x^2)+(y^2)=4;
```

As you can see the first one is an implicit function, specifically a line. The other 2 are two explicit functions, specifically circumferences. I need to plot them in the same 3D graph with axis x,y,z to study them. I just need the ranges of the 3 axis to be from 0 to 2. I tried using `meshgrid` and `mesh` but it seems it's only working for the first function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind redefining your functions a bit, you can do it like this with some math:

```
%function 1
y1=linspace(0,2,1000);
z1=y1-1;
x1=zeros(1,length(y1));

%function 2
theta2=linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,1000);
x2=2*(cos(theta2)).^2;
y2=sqrt(2*x2).*sin(theta2);
z2=zeros(1,length(x2));

%function 3
theta3=linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
x3=2*(cos(theta3));
y3=2*sin(theta3);
z3=zeros(1,length(x2));

%plot
plot3([x1' x2' x3'],[y1' y2' y3'],[z1' z2' z3']);
axis equal;
xlim([0 2]);
ylim([0 2]);
zlim([0 2]);
```

Comment: It seems somehow accurate but I don't really understand what are you doing. Plus there's a function that isn't plotted well (`(x^2)+(y^2)=2x;`, I don't know if it's function 2 or 3 from your code). Can you please explain what did you do and how can I fix that function?

Comment: It's my function 2. What I did was basically to use that (x^2+y^2)=r^2, where r is distance to the origin (0,0). Then, as x=r*cos(theta)=sqrt(2*x)*cos(theta), I solved for x and I got x=2*(cos(theta))^2. Then r=sqrt(2*x) and I could obtain y. And yes, there was a mistake, I was missing a sqrt() in function 2 y. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

If available use `ezplot` from the symbolic toolbox:

```
syms x y
ezplot((x^2)+(y^2)==2*x)
```

Otherwise use the identical named function in a standard MATLAB installation

```
ezplot('(x^2)+(y^2)=2*x')
```

Comment: thanks, I tried it and managed to plot the two explicit functions using `hold on` but when I plot `z=y-1` and try to change the view it seems like the axis are still in 2D (z and y and not x).

Comment: Symbolic toolbox available?

Comment: No... using standard MATLAB installation